# Inaccessible fields in records

Tags: haskell

A bit more [indirectly] regarding my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233587/isomorphism-lenses): there, my definition of lens was

```
data Iso α β = Iso { fw :: α -> β, bw :: β -> α }
data Lens α β = forall r. Lens (Iso α (β, r))
```

And this is fine, as long as the module is imported unqualified. Problems begin with the case where it is, and, for `import qualified Util.Lens as L`, I get an error about `fw` not being a (visible) field of constructor `Iso`. The code itself is trivial,

```
data BValue = BValue { p :: Float, d :: Float, q :: Float } deriving Show
pLens :: L.Lens BValue Float
pLens = L.Lens (L.Iso { fw = pFwd, bw = pBwd })
```

The Util.Lens exports both `Lens(..)` and `Iso(..)`. TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The record fields need to be qualified as well, i.e.:

```
L.Iso { L.fw = pFwd, L.bw = pBwd }
```

Comment: Thanks, it seemed obvious but weird enough for asking explicitly.